# how i rename this file?

Tags: php, image, rename

i have this script but i want to rename the file:

```
 <?php

         $fieldname = $_REQUEST['fieldname'];

                $uploaddir = 'uploads/';
                $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES[$fieldname]['name']);


                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            //i want to rename the file before i can upload it



                 echo $uploadfile; // "success"

                } 

          else {

                echo "error";
                }

        ?>
```

how can i rename the file before i upload it to uploads/ directory!!

Comment: Was it that hard to google "PHP rename"? http://www.google.com/search?q=php+rename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `move_uploaded_file` function does exactly that. When you are moving the uploaded file from the temporary location to the uploads/ directory, you can change the name of it.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], 'uploads/whatever-i-want');
```

Comment: can you give me an exmaple of how i can chnage the $uploadfile variable then the parameters if move_uploaded_file

Answer (score 3):

What ever you pass as the 2nd parameter to `move_uploaded_file` will be used as the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a different target name in `$uploadfile`.

Comment: can you give me an example, im a newbie to php sorry :(, i would really like to chnage the varible of $uploadfile, rather than change the move_uploaded_file parameters!! its more cleaner!! thanks

Comment: @Jhon but why? You'd just have to replace `basename($_FILES[$fieldname]['name'])` by whatever you want the file name to be

Comment: but when i do that, when uploaded it deosnt reconise the extension

Comment: @Jhon well, then you'll need to get the extension using [`pathinfo()`](http://www.php.net/pathinfo) and add that to the new name